# how to reapir meme command in discord.jsv14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can I send it without error? Image variable is because it is random link on this web.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, Embed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("meme")
    .setDescription("send meme"),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const url = await fetch("https://ivall.pl/memy");
    const image = await url.json();

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder().setImage(image);

    await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
    });
  },
};
```

and error
[image]

Answer (score -2):

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, AttachmentBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("meme")
    .setDescription("send a random meme"),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    var { url } = await fetch(`https://ivall.pl/memy`, {method: 'post'}).then(response => response.json());

    let SetImg = new AttachmentBuilder(`${url}`, {name: 'image.jpg'});

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder().setImage('attachment://image.jpg');

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], files: [SetImg] });
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).